# get and display the right datas with route parameters filtering and a doctrine query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

To begin I have this SQl request:

```
SELECT  pc.id, pc.nom_point_comptage, e.id, e.nom_ensemble, p.id, p.nom_parc
FROM points_comptage pc , ensembles e , parcs_immobilier p
WHERE pc.ensembles_id = e.id
AND e.parcs_immobilier_id = p.id
```

This query allows me to get the `points comptage` which are in the `ensembles` owned to a specific `parc`

So in my symfony controller I made a DQL with doctrine. This is the code for the controller:

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/gestioncompteurs/pointscomptageByparcs", name="dataTablePointsComptageParc")
 * @Method("get")
 */
public function pointsComptageByParcAction($nomParc)
{
  $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

  $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT  p.nomParc, e.nomEnsemble, pc.invariantPointComptage /*and more like my SQL request...*/
                             FROM MySpaceMyBundle:ParcsImmobilier p, MySpaceMyBundle:Ensembles e, MySpaceMyBundle:PointsComptage pc
                               WHERE pc.ensembles = e.id
                               AND e.parcsImmobilier = p.id');

  $pointComptage = $query->getResult();

  return $this->render('MySpaceMyBundle:PointsComptage:dataTablePointsComptage.html.twig', array(
        'pointComptage' => $pointComptage));
}
```

But in my twig, first I need to filter by parc, so I create a select tag where there are all my parcs like this:

```
<select class="form-control input" id="filterByParc" name="filterByParc">
  <option value="" disabled selected>sélectionnez un parc</option>
    {% for parcs in parc %}
      <option value="{{ path('dataTablePointsComptageParc', {'nomParc': parcs.nomParc}) }}">{{ parcs.nomParc }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

As you can see, the value for the selected options in my select tag is a path(url) for a view. Because I need to return in javascript a datatables filtering by the parc I choose (route parameter).

All works well, that is to say, my controller and my javascript display correctly my datatable, but with no data.

On **phpMyAdmin**, my request works well, but **not** with **Doctrine** in my controller.

To explain exactly what I am trying to do and what I need:

> **first**: I select a parc name in my select tag in my view;
>   **second**: my choice returns
>   me a datatable filtering by the name of my parc I choose, so the datas in my
>   table have to be all the `points comptage` in my `ensembles` owned to the
>   `parc` I choose first in the select tag.

Someone know where my problem occured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the logic of filtering with a DQL and a route parameter.

See my controller code here:

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/gestioncompteurs/pointscomptageByparcs", name="dataTablePointsComptageParc")
 * @Method("get")
 */
public function pointsComptageByParcAction($nomParc)
{
  $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

  $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT  p.nomParc, e.nomEnsemble, pc.invariantPointComptage /*and more like my SQL request...*/
                             FROM MySpaceMyBundle:ParcsImmobilier p, MySpaceMyBundle:Ensembles e, MySpaceMyBundle:PointsComptage pc
                               WHERE pc.ensembles = e.id
                               AND e.parcsImmobilier = p.id
                               AND p.nomParc = '$nomParc'");

  $pointComptage = $query->getResult();

  return $this->render('MySpaceMyBundle:PointsComptage:dataTablePointsComptage.html.twig', array(
        'pointComptage' => $pointComptage, 'parc' => $parc));
}
```

I need to pass the `$nomParc` in my DQl to recover the right datas in order to match with the data I pass to the route parameter.

Comment: Ok, but I would advice against doing it this way. You should always utilize **prepared statements** in order to mitigate SQL injection. Use `Query::setParameter()`...

Comment: Yes, I see in the doc that it is actually better to use **prepared statement**, I am working on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this makes perfect sense.

`Doctrine` operates on entities via DQL (not SQL). At very least you could try putting `getArrayResult()` instead of `getResult()`.

In fact, you should probably use [DBAL Connection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.5/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Connection.html):

```
$em = .... // Your EntityManager
$sql = " .... ";
$pointComptage = $em->getConnection()->fetchAssoc($sql);

return $this->render('MySpaceMyBundle:PointsComptage:dataTablePointsComptage.html.twig', array(
    'pointComptage' => $pointComptage));
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, It allows me to undrstand how filtering correctly in a DQL in reading the doctrine doc. See my answer I wrote, it's the solution I found and it works well.